# Fill a MsAccess table using a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, oledbdataadapter

I have to transfer a whole datatable, OriginaDataTable, into another Ms Access table with the same structure. I've tryied with DataAdapter but something went wrong as no rows are written.

```
using (OleDbDataAdapter a = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [TableToFill]", cnn))
{
    a.Fill(OriginaDataTable);
}
```

I'm missing something?

Comment: you've mixed up your input and output tables?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I basically have to transfer the OriginalDataTable into that MsAccess table. I would avoid a cycle with INSERT INTO

Comment: You got data from Access to `DataTable`. Now you have to put data from `DataTable` to another Access table: `a.Update(OriginaDataTable)`. Note that the `InsertCommand`/`UpdateCommand` property must be correctly initialized in `DataAdapter`